# Web Components not working for Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, web-component, firefox-addon-webextensions

Overall what I am trying to achieve is injecting a custom element into the dom. I see it being injected, but I get a `TypeError: this.functionName is not a function` message.

I've defined my component simlar to this:

```
class Foo extends HTMLElement{
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.doSomething();
  }

  doSomething() {
    //does something.
  }
}
```

When it goes to call `doSomething()` I received the function not defined error. I've tried renaming the function, defining other functions and trying to call those, but nothing works.

My manifest is defined similar to:

```
{"content_scripts"[{
"js":["custom-elements.min.js", "MyWebComponent.js"],
"run_at": "document_start"}]}
```

I have also tried the polyfill `webcomponents-bundle.js`, but received a `TypeError: Bh is null` message, and decided not to jump down that rabit hole since the code is obfuscated.

I should note that the extension works fine in Chrome and Safari, and even Edge.

EDIT: It may not be obvious, but I am using the Custom Elements v1 polyfill https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements.

EDIT: After speaking with someone in the addons Slack channel for Firefox I've come to learn that this is a known issue where functions just go 'missing'. Also there is limited access to properties in the dom which is potentially due to built in security limitations for browser extensions. My work around is just to use `document.createElement('my-element-name')` to create my custom elements, and then attach the properties later.

Comment: Yes it's an incompatibiliy between the polyfill and Firefox